# Extract the URL of stored html file

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I have stored some html files and renamed them. Is there some possible way I can extract the URL of the html file in python.

EDIT:
I wish to find the URL of the .html file and not the links present in it. I am looking for a generalised approach as I have many files.

Comment: The URL you retrieved each file from?

Comment: Can you find any meta tag in that file ?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: maybe you could provide a sample

Comment: You can't unless you store the urls explicitly or as @sachinsaxena mentioned, the url is stored in the meta tags.

Comment: @sachinsaxena Can you give some sample code.

Comment: @Rob please check now.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia if you look at the source of this particular page you will find something like - <meta property="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321265/extract-the-url-of-stored-html-file"/>

Comment: Useless downvotes for no reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only possible if the file itself contains that URL, which is not very common. So it depends on the files you have downloaded. Look for a  `<link rel="canonical" ...>` as this is the way search engines [recommend](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) to publish the canonical address to a web page. If they have that tag you can use that URL.

Otherwise you are out of luck. You should rewrite your spider to save the URL together with the document.